Is it possible to customize the top-level test names in VS Code's Testing view?
I’m using VS Code’s Testing panel to run my test suite (configured via pytest), and I’ve noticed that the top-level test items appear with generic names like tests. This happens even though I have multiple test directories from different projects, and it’s hard to distinguish between them.
Is there a way to customize the names of these top-level items?
VSCode testing panel with settings
I've looked through settings, but haven't been able to find anything. Just using the projects names would be helpful.
